# providedIn and providers misunderstanding

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

We have our own `ui-kit` library and it has the service with `providedIn: 'root'` (let it be service A) and there another one service which just `@Injectable` (let it be service B  which injected into service A). I provided service B in `app.module`. The result is that service A is `undefined`. As far as I know, `providedIn: 'root'` is the same as provide in `app.module`. Then I can not understand why it is undefined ... Thanks

Comment: You must provide the server A in the app.module, even if you use provideIn: 'root'.

Comment: But why? I thought thet providedIn: 'root' == providers in app.module?

Comment: Service A isn't undefined if I change scope of service B to providedIn: 'root' too

Comment: Look here ;) https://medium.com/@MatheusCAS/injecting-a-service-into-another-service-in-angular-3b253df5c21 And my bad, you can use only provedIn: 'root'

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, do not both services have the scope? Because I thought they have